# CRUD detail screen, conditional new or edit

Tags: angularjs, crud, angular-template

I'm working on a CRUD detail screen in Angular and wish to reuse a single template.  Here's the initial template psuedo-code, the crude beginnings of an edit screen...

```
<h1>{{fixtureType.Label}}</h1>
<form>
    <span>Fixture Type Details</span>
      <label>Type</label>
      <input>{{fixtureType.Type}}</input>
      <label>Watts</label>
      <input>{{fixtureType.Watts}}</input>
      <label>Cost</label>
      <input>{{fixtureType.Cost}}</input>
</form>
```

Suppose I want to conditionally use the same template as a *new* screen as well, that would look something like this

```
<h1>New Fixture Type</h1>
<form>
    <span>Fixture Type Details</span>
      <label>Type</label>
      <input/>
      <label>Watts</label>
      <input/>
      <label>Cost</label>
      <input/>
</form>
```

If this were straight Javascript, a simple condition like `bIsEdit = fixtureType != null` would do the trick.  From what I've read so far there is no conditional or way to drop in a chunk of JS into an Angular view.., or is this where I reach for a custom *directive* or *filter*?

Now I could have 2 views and handle the routing appropriately, but would prefer to have a single one to avoid code duplication.

So what is the Angular way to handle something like this?

Comment: Couldn't you just edit an empty model?

Comment: I like this idea, but currently the JS doesn't know what a FixtureType model looks like unless it comes from the server.  The two options I could think of 1. cooking up an object that looks like a FixtureType on the client 2. Hitting up the server for a blank FixtureType - both sound rough.

Comment: Actually, after some experimentation it appears I can get away w/ stuffing a blank anonymous object in place of the model and get no complaints on the console.  Works for me!  But I've also taken a cue from Mark to switch on the route, more details on the approach I've taken in a comment on his answer.

Comment: Another update, Mike, now that I've gotten a basic understanding of the Angular `$resource`, I'm using `$scope.fixtureType = new FixtureType();`!

Comment: I like this question because the answers illustrate two different possible approaches to a common AngularJS question: how to do conditional logic in a template, when there's no ng-if. One technique is to use ng-switch, another is ng-show/ng-hide, and a third possibility is to write your own ngIf directive.

Comment: Custom `ng-if` directive - neat idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer separate routes for each.  To keep the edit and new HTML together, you could use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) with essentially two templates, but consider putting them both into one partial, so you can ng-include it in the two different views:

```
<span ng-switch on="mode">
  <span ng-switch-when="edit">
    <h1>{{fixtureType.Label}}</h1>
    <form>
      <span>Fixture Type Details</span>
        <label>Type</label>
        <input ng-model='fixtureType.Type' ...>
    ...
  </span>
  <span ng-switch-default>
    <h1>New Fixture Type</h1>
    <form>
         <span>Fixture Type Details</span>
         <label>Type</label>
         <input ng-model="fixtureType.Type" ...>
    ...
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Seems like the switch is somewhat if you're trying to use an include.  The problem is the `{{fixtureType.<field>}}` bindings in the template.  Even with the `ng-switch` in the outer template you still have to cope with those bindings in the included template.  In the end I've taken a hybrid of your suggestion to switch on the route and use a blank model as Mike suggested.  The 'switching' in this case is done in the controller though.  Therein the code either pumps in a null FixtureType (read: `{}`) or hits up the server, based on the route-provided id.

Answer (score 3):

I use following approach to minimize form duplication when differences between new and editable versions aren't too complex:

```html
<form ng-submit="mySubmitMethod()">
<!-- fields models bound to "activeItem"-->
  <button >
     <span ng-show="editMode>Update</span>
      <span ng-show="!editMode">Create</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

```js
    $scope.activeItem={};
    $scope.editMode=false;
    $scope.mySubmitMethod=function(){
        if($scope.editMode){
            /* do update of existing*/
        }else{
           /* process new form*/
       }
        $scope.resetform()
    });

   $scope.EditUser=function(user){
        $scope.editMode=true;
        $scope.activeItem=angular.copy( user);
   })

  $scope.newUser=function(){
        $scope.editMode=false;
        $scope.activeItem={};
   })
```

Comment: Very similar to what I ended up with.  Also, I didn't know about `ng-show`, thanks for that!